# ComplexEigenSolver for complex matrix with boost multiprecision

Tags: c++, boost, eigen

I can't compute eigen values and eigen vectors for new type of matrix initialized by means of boost multiprecision.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<Eigen/Dense>
#include<Eigen/Eigenvalues>
#include<boost/multiprecision/eigen.hpp>
#include<boost/multiprecision/cpp_complex.hpp>
#include<complex>

using namespace std;
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace boost::multiprecision;

int main() {

   Matrix<cpp_complex_single, Dynamic, Dynamic> A = Matrix<cpp_complex_single, Dynamic, Dynamic>::Identity(3,3);
   ComplexEigenSolver<Matrix<cpp_complex_single, Dynamic, Dynamic>> ces(A);

   return 0;
}
```

Error log is quite long, so I decided to put it on pastebin, here is the link https://pastebin.com/XfvLT9y4. Summarizing: is there any way to compute eigen problem for new type of complex matrix initialized with boost multiprecision ?

Comment: I encountered the same issue, there seems to be something wrong with boosts multiprecision complex types & eigen. I use now Julia.